# boost program_options add_options return value

Tags: c++, boost

I am currently learning the `boost::program_options::options_description` library and encounter the following query.
When we call the `add_options` method of `boost::program_options::options_description` class it returns the object `options_description_easy_init` and using this object we add the different command line argument options.
Ex.

```
boost::program_options::options_description objDescri("Allowed options");
    objDescri.add_options()
        ("help","To get the help")
        ("compression", boost::program_options::value<int>()->default_value(90),"Compression level");
```

My question since add_options is returning the object by value and not by reference, then how the options are getting added in options_description.
The declaration of add_options is:

```
 options_description_easy_init add_options();
```

Comment: this is well observed!

Answer (score 2):

Well, actually  `options_description_easy_init` is a proxy object referencing actual options container. So yes, the method returns a copy of such a proxy,

see `/usr/include/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp` (or wherever your boost headers reside) for more gory details